# AWS Mobile Hub Sample React APPProject Error

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-mobilehub

I didn't even modify my backend for the sample react app I used: 
https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-mobile-react-sample

I just tried awsmobile push and run, and it works the first time. But the next day I came back, it just says the following:

`The stack \'arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:XXXXX:stack/MOBILEHUB-XXXXXXX-Development/XXXXXXXXXX\' in Amazon CloudFormation has been modified outside of the Mobile Hub. This stage \'Development\' can no longer be modified inside of Mobile Hub.`

Comment: Please format your code properly and give more details

Answer (score 0):

You can click the banner on the top to unlock your stack. Note it may return to the original version of your app.